# Attempt to fetch Objects returns Uncaught TypeError: Object function ParsePromise()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, vue.js, es6-promise

The following code returns a `Document` object based on its id and then finds its corresponding sections based on the object. `document` is a Parse object and `document.toJSON` turns this object into a Javascript object. `sections` is an array of Javascript objects.

**main.js:**

```
  data () {
    return {
      id: '',
      document: {},
      sections: [],
      content: ''
    }
  },

  route: {
    data ({ to }) {
      return store.first(to.params.id).then((document) => ({
        document: document.toJSON(),
        sections: store.findSection(document).then((result) => this.sections = result)
      }))
    }
  },
```

**store.js:**

```
const store = {}

store.findSection = (obj) => {
  const Section = Parse.Object.extend('Section')
  const query = new Parse.Query(Section)
  query.equalTo('document', obj)
  return query.find().then((results) =>
    _.map(results, (result) =>
      result.toJSON()
    )
  )
}

export default store
```

For some reason, `store.findSelection` throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ParsePromise() {
    _classCallCheck(this, ParsePromise);

    this._resolved = false;
    this._rejected = false;
    this._resolvedCallbacks = [];
    this._rejectedCallbacks = [];
  } has no method 'all'
```

What could be the problem, and how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

Strangely, if I do something like this (under `route`):

**main.js:**

```
  methods: {
    submit () {
      store.findSection(store.transform(this.document)).then((result) => this.sections = result)
    }
  }
```

**store.js:**

```
store.transform = (obj) => {
  obj.className = 'Document'
  return Parse.Object.fromJSON(obj)
}
```

`store.findSection` works and outputs the right thing: `[Object, Object, Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assigning a promise to `sections` data.

A better way would be to chain the promise again to find the section, and return the result at the end of the promise chain:

```
return ...then((document) => { return findSection(document)})
.then((sections) => ({
    document: document.toJSON(),
    sections: sections
})
```

an alternative way would be watching `document` data for changes and using `vue-async-data` plugin (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-async-data) to update sections (note: the router would only be used to set `document` in this case):

```
watch {
   document: reloadAsyncData
},
asyncData () {
   return store.findSection(document).then((result) => {
      return {sections:result}
   })
},
```